# Creating with gorms and many2many

Tags: rest, go, go-gorm

I have the following models

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Languages         []Language `gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`
}

type Language struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  Users              []User `gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`
}
```

and for creating a language I do:

```
func CreateLanguage(db *gorm.DB, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    language := models.Language{}

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&language); err != nil {
        respondError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    if err := db.Save(&language).Error; err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    respondWithJSON(w, http.StatusCreated, language)
}
```

when I check the database, I have the table `Language` filled with the language I created, but `user_languages` was not filled. I thought `gorm` was in charge of updating the intermediate table when you user `gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`, and the engine will figure out how to manage creations.

So question: how to manage creation with `gorm` when you have `many2many` relationships?

Answer (score 1):

Gorm has a feature to auto save associations and its references from the struct. In your case you need to pass correct JSON object, for example if you pass:

```
{
    "Name": "EN",
    "Users": [
        {
            "ID": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Gorm will create new language with name "EN" and join it with the user row found by id 1 by creating new row in user_language table.

Read more about Gorm associations: http://gorm.io/docs/associations.html